# Flink and non-keyed window state

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams, flink-streaming

I'm creating a Flink application that simply forwards windowed incoming Kafka events to another Kafka topic with an addition of start and end markers for each window - so for example, for a window of 1 hour containing `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, I will sink
`start_timestamp, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, end_timestamp` into a different Kafka topic. Potentially, there will be some other transforms later on, but in general, for N events coming in, I'm always going to be emitting at least N+2 events.

As I understand, using `windowAll()` with a `ProcessAllWindowFunction` that will inject start and end markers should do this.
My question is around state management. I'll be using RocksDb state backend - will it also keeps persisting internal window state even for this non-keyed stream? My main concern is to be able to keep the state in the window so that I'm not reprocessing it again, especially for large windows.

Comment: Can You please elaborate, I am not really sure what do You mean by keeping the state in the window.

Comment: So let's say my pipeline is simply `stream.map(object -> object.incrField1()).windowAll(1.hour).process(MyProcessor())`. Then as I understand, the state that MyProcessor keeps accumulating as an Iterable<MyObject> will be just the original list of objects that came in with field1 incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something this simple, I'd use a `FlatMap` (with parallelism set to 1) that keeps in state the time of the current window and the last event time. Whenever a record arrives, if it's in a new hourly window, I'd emit the `end_timestamp` (last event time), the `start_timestamp` (from the new record), and update the saved state's current hour. In all case the last event time in state is also updated. This assumes your incoming events are strictly ordered, so you don't have to worry about late data.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @kkrugler's approach, since it will avoid the cost of keeping all that state around. But to answer your question, yes, a `windowAll` can use the RocksDB state backend to persist its contents. Under the hood a `windowAll` is actually a keyed window with a special constant key. So even though RocksDB can only be used to manage keyed state, it works.